Microfrontends: Angular, Module Federation and DevExtreme/DevExtreme-Angular
I'm developing microfrontends with Angular and Module Federation (package "@angular-architects/module-federation@15.0.3" due to the version of Angular it deals with).
I'm including an old application to a microfrontend.

I transformed all the components of the old app to standalone.

I eliminated unnecessary modules.

I transformed the old app into a microfrontend.

I included it in the microfrontends shell.


All components that do not occupy "devextreme@20.2.4 and devextreme-angular@20.2.4" work perfectly. But when including a component that uses "devextreme/devextreme-angular" this error appears.
core.mjs:11752 ERROR 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6001:19)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:911:40)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:917:60)
    at Object.DxIntegrationModule_Factory [as useFactory] (devextreme-angular-core.js:838:182)
    at Object.factory (core.mjs:6268:38)
    at core.mjs:6169:43
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:867:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:6168:17)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6038:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:911:40)

The strange thing is that the rest of the components without "devextreme" work perfectly.
I tried to insert the "DxIntegrationModule" module into the "imports" of the standalone components.
I looked for information but it seems that no one has seen this. In fact, there is almost no information from the "DxIntegrationModule" module.
